# How to write an Angular directive for input and contenteditable

Tags: angularjs, tags, directive

my html is taking input in two form, `input` and `contenteditable div` . I want to write one directive that handles both, but I cannot find a way to figure out which tag has called the function (because Angular's JQLite doesnt provide a is() or get() function). The following code will be complete if I can figure out to evaluate IS_INPUT_TAG:

```
function funct() { return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        // view -> model
        element.bind('input', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                    if(IS_INPUT_TAG)
                      ctrl.$setViewValue(element.val());
                    else
                          ctrl.$setViewValue(element.text());
                scope.watchCallback(element.attr('data-ng-model'));
            });
          });
        // model -> view
        ctrl.$render = function() {
            if(IS_INPUT_TAG)
                  element.val(ctrl.$viewValue);
             else
                  element.text(ctrl.$viewValue);
        };
     }};
}

app.directive('input', funct);
app.directive('contenteditable', funct);
```

Comment: Use an attribute: `<input is-input="true"` and `<div is-input="false"`. Check for the same in the directive.

Comment: yeah, thats what i have done in the interim, but its not really clean. lemme wait for a better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directive, you can make use of the `element` parameter of the linking function to identify the tag on which the directive is applied. You can then use that in your IF condition as follows:

```
ctrl.$render = function() {
    var tagname = element["0"].tagName;

    if(tagName === "INPUT")
          element.val(ctrl.$viewValue);
    else
          element.text(ctrl.$viewValue);
};
```

After, this you can simply attach the directive to the `input` and the `div` tags as an attribute to the tags to identify the tag to which the directive is applied.

Comment: you champion :) wonder where did you get the api for it, or did you dive into the src code. thanks a lot